# How do I import a non-directed graph in graphml format?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, import

I have created a graph with undirected edges, and I'm trying to import it into *Mathematica*.  However, when I import it, I get directed edges.

```
g = Import["document.graphml", "Graph",  VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

Comment: Please, post the example you are trying to import and any relevant information.

Comment: What is in your graphml file allows _Mathematica_ to distinguish a non-directed edge from a directed edge? Also, it is easy to change directed edges into undirected edges by post-processing the imported graph. Did you try that?

Answer (score 1):

```
g = Graph[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 1}, VertexLabels -> "Name"];
h = UndirectedGraph[g, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

Answer (score 1):

I said in a comment that is easy to change directed edges into undirected edges. Here is an example offered as proof-of-concept.

```
g = Graph[{DirectedEdge[a, b], DirectedEdge[b, c], DirectedEdge[c, a]}]
h = Graph[EdgeList[g] /. DirectedEdge -> UndirectedEdge]
h//FullForm
```

> ```
> FullForm[
>     Graph[{a, b, c}, 
>       {UndirectedEdge[a, b], UndirectedEdge[b, c], UndirectedEdge[c, a]}]]
> ```